How to map notes to numerical values
I have a BASIC code that uses numerical values 1,2,3,...,15 for notes and values 2,4,8,16 for delays of each note.
Someone has written the pieces and I need to enter them in code. An example of a piece is as follows:
music1:
data 0,  _
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0,15,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,0,8,7,6,5,4, _
3,2,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0,15,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,0,8, _
7,6,5,4,3,2,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0,15,15,14,13,12,11, _
10,9,0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0,15,15, _
14,13,12,11,10,9,0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,13
delay1:
data 0,  _
8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8, _
8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8, _
8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8, _
8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,8

Entering these from paper is very tiresome and error-prone.
I was wondering if there is tool or programming library that can do this for me, so that I can process the notes one by one and map them to the corresponding number?
I didn't find a programming tag, so I'm leaving a midi tag (not sure if it fits here).
P.S.
I have the pieces written on paper (as shown below), and I have to write them in code as shown in the example. I think I can get the notes of the pieces from the author. So, I was wondering if I could somehow translate the notes to the above format for a large number of pieces.

Currently I'm entering the numbers manually. But, I suppose there might be a more automated way.

I don't quite understand the problem.  You have the numbers in code above; are you asking about an easier way to create code such as the example you've given?

@phoog please see the updated post

Thanks.  That's a lot clearer.  This is not a generalized answer, but if there is some algorithmic pattern in the piece, which it seems like there might be, then perhaps you could write something to generate that.  For example, I once wrote a function that takes two parameters, a series of arrays of pitches and a rhythmic pattern, and used it to generate all but the last three measures of the first prelude of Bach's WTC Book 1.  This means entering 5 data points per measure plus 8 data points for the pattern (168 in total) instead of 16 data points per measure (512 total).

Thank you for editing the question, but it seems to me that it has actually little to do with music, as you start with handwritten number notation, and you want to end up with the same notation, digitized and formatted appropriately. It might be better to ask on a different site. Possibly also split it into two questions: how to recognize text, and how to format the text as BASIC code? Please also specify, what approach have you tried, and what is the largest obstacle.

@user1079505 let's assume I can get the musical notation in the form of a MIDI file from the author of the pieces as he is music teacher. Then, my question is how I can process the MIDI file and map it to numbers.

Mehdi, is there a reason that you are creating your own system to map pitches to notes instead of using MIDI? For example, if you're trying to write a program to play a piece of music, there are many off-the-shelf solutions (both user-facing apps and programming libraries) that simply take a MIDI file and play it back. If you're trying to do something else, it might be easier to use a MIDI programming library to extract the data you need.

(If this is a small project or you're almost done with it, though, learning how to work with MIDI is a deep rabbit hole you don't have to go down.)

Thanks Kevin for the insight. I think I'm gonna weigh the possibilities and situation. In the long run and for a general automated working approach, I will need the MIDI solution I believe.

The problem consists of two separate issues. One is getting data in your format, which is easy. The other is getting notation from paper into data. Here you can use many approaches. If you have experience in some note editor you could use this to first enter the music. Or you could use a Lilypond-like notation to enter the music:
c8 d8 e8 d8 dis4 e4

and then use simple string matching and replacement to extract from this
c d e d dis e

and
8 8 8 8 4 4

and then translate the first one to
0 2 4 2 3 4

or whatever. There is also music ocr, which works, well, not too accurately.
So really the answer depends on whatever workflow you are comfortable with. Personally I’d maybe do the whole thing in Lilypond, which means having to write scheme code
% Entering music
music = {
  c8 d e d dis4 e
}

{ \transpose c c' \music }

% Extracting duration property from all notes
durations =
#(map (lambda (m) (ly:music-property m 'duration))
      (ly:music-property music 'elements))

% Extracting pitch property from all notes
pitches =
#(map (lambda (m) (ly:music-property m 'pitch))
      (ly:music-property music 'elements))

% Turn durations into number
duration_fmt =
#(map ly:duration->string durations)

% Calculate semitones from middle c minus 1 octave (or same octave
% and notate in the correct octave, but this way entering the pitches is easier)
pitches_steps =
#(map (lambda (x) (+ x 12)) (map ly:pitch-steps pitches))

% Formatting
#(display "music1:\ndata 0, _\n")
#(display (string-join (map number->string pitches_steps) ","))
#(newline)
#(display "delay1:\ndata 0, _\n")
#(display (string-join duration_fmt ","))
#(newline)

This has the disadvantage of having to write Scheme code, but it has the benefit of being able to abuse Lilypond’s capabilities for running the numbers. Also it means you can get a proof pdf in one go.
If you wish to use a graphical notation software you’ll need to somehow then extract that data. The simplest way would be to either use midi output (which means having to deal with durations) or musicXML output (which means having to first extract the notes from the XML). MIDI only stores tempo and an on and an off event for each chromatic pitch, so pitch→number is very easy, but getting the durations means you need to take difference between on and off, round it to a grid and maybe also correct for humanized playback (staccato and stuff).

I didn't quite get it. If I have the MIDI file for the pieces, can the notes and their durations be extracted accurately?

@MehdiHaghgoo The notes are not much of a problem. But extracting the length is a bit tricky, as MIDI will not tell you: A quarter note, but it will tell you: Note on at one point in time, note off at a different time. But considering your edit it seems like you already have the pieces notated in your code rather than standard notation?
